Why text-generation-webui "--listen-port" not working?
I have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last) 
E:\text-generation-webui-user\server.py:254 in <module>                                                                                                      
253         # Launch the web UI                                                                                                                   
> 254         create_interface()                                                                                                                    
255         while True:                                                                                                                           
 E:\text-generation-webui-user\server.py:133 in create_interface                                                                             
132         ui_parameters.create_ui(shared.settings['preset'])  # Parameters tab                                                                  
> 133         ui_model_menu.create_ui()  # Model tab                                                                                                
134         training.create_ui()  # Training tab                                                                                                 
E:\text-generation-webui-user\modules\ui_model_menu.py:77 in create_ui                                                                     
76                 shared.gradio['loader'] = gr.Dropdown(label="Model loader", choices=load                                                      
>  77                 with gr.Box():                                                                                                                
78                     with gr.Row():                                                                                                            
AttributeError: module 'gradio' has no attribute 'Box'

I tried this command:
python server.py --listen-port 7860 --listen-host 0.0.0.0 --share

but I can not access Text-generation-webui with the IP adress: 192.XXX[...]:7860. I tried to change the port, but I still can't access it. Any ideas?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

first idea: show FULL error message. Second idea: explain doesn't work. We can't run it, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments).

last idea: show code which makes problem. I don't know if gradio has Box - maybe you need Checkbox instead of Box

The problem, likely lies in your server.py as it doesn't seem to be able to get gradio.Box.  Please include your server.py in your question, especially the import statements.

try this command
python server.py --listen --listen-host 0.0.0.0 --listen-port 7860


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
